# How can I change the value that is transmitted in post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I have this sample

**CODE HTML:**

```
  <form method="post" class="add-patient">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="lastname">Phone<span class="star">*</span></label>
                    <input class="required-input _phone" id="primary_phone" type="text" name="phone" maxlength="10"  value="<?php echo $prInfo->clinicphone; ?>" placeholder="1234567890">
                </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="pull-right" id="save-bottom-add">
                    <button type="Submit" id="btn-sub" class="btn btn-primary btn-save" onclick="DoSubmit()">Submit</button>
               </div>
          </div>
   </form>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
function DoSubmit(){
        var firstFormat = $("#primary_phone").val();  //ex format:(123) 123-1234
        var lastFormat = firstFormat.replace(/\s/g, ''); //the new format should be: 123-123-1234
        console.log(lastFormat);
        return true;
    }
```

What I want to do is transform the format text of an input before submit and pass it in the new format to `POST`

It is correct that we have chosen method?
What is the solution to transform this format?

Can you help me find a solution to this problem please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i suggest just mask the input so you dont need to change anything anymore. check this [link](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: You'll have to set the `input`'s value to the new one (eg: `$("#primary_phone").val(lastFormat);`)

Comment: You must change the parameters to replace function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you on track

```
function DoSubmit(){
    var firstFormat = $("#primary_phone").val();  //ex format:(123) 123-1234
    var lastFormat = firstFormat.replace(/\D/g,"").replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'); //new format: 123-123-1234
    console.log(lastFormat);
    // also do any substitution of value(s) here
    // Ex:- $("#primary_phone").val(lastFormat);
    return true;
}

$(".add-patient").submit(function() {
    DoSubmit();
});
```

`.submit()` is a shortcut for `.on( "submit", handler )` in the first variation, and `.trigger( "submit" )` in the third. See [docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

**UPDATE:** Thanks @titus for pointing out about non-numeric chars.
See the updated code and [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y17mn582/) for demo.

Comment: @JohnSmith See the update. Changed `replace()` for your need. Hope that helps!

Comment: the regex first broke the input string into 3 digits, 3 digits and 4 digits, then combined them to the desired format.

Comment: Unfortunately the format remains the same, not change

Comment: @JohnSmith That is because you'll need to remove all non-numerical characters first.

Comment: @JohnSmith: see the updated code and the fiddle for demo. Thanks Titus for pointing out about non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function DoSubmit(){
    var firstFormat = $("#primary_phone").val();  //ex format:(123) 123-1234
    //First, replace all non-numeric character then, replace all groups of 3 numbers (not the ending group) with the group itself fallowed by a line.
    var lastFormat = firstFormat.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/(\d{3}(?!$))/g,"$1-"); 
    // Change the input's value to the new one.
    $("#primary_phone").val(lastFormat);
    return true;
}
```